# php echo to elixir iex stdin

Tags: php, echo, elixir, stdin

ok, I know I'm doing something weird here but I gotta do it.

So my elixir program needs to run one PHP script and take the information from that script, but it never comes in. I can manually run the php script and it works fine. At the bottom of the script it says:

```
echo $avar->getPUId();
```

So it's printing it out to echo I guess. I get the data I need when I run it from a command line:

```
C:\PHP>php.exe "-f" "C:\pap.php" "613b8859"
37a69912
```

But when I run it from iex I get nothing:

```
iex(1)> System.cmd("C:\\PHP\\php.exe", ["-f", "C:\\pap.php", "613b8859"])
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Now, if I mess up on the filename or something php will give me an error in response saying like:

```
iex(1)> System.cmd("C:\\PHP\\php.exe", ["-f", "C:\\pap321.php", "613b8859"])
{"Could not open input file: c:/pap123.php\n", 1}
...
```

so I know I can talk to PHP, and it can talk back to me with errors, but echo isn't caught by my elixir application that calls it apparently. Is there any other way I can grab the data as it comes out of the PHP script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

https://github.com/alco/porcelain

```
result = Porcelain.shell("C:\\PHP\\php.exe -f C:\\pap.php 613b8859")
IO.inspect result.out
```

it worked great.